# Why does this attached event not fire?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

hy there!

i'm having that simple server-control:

```
public sealed class FooControl : CompositeControl
{
    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            return this._fooValidator.ValidationGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            this._fooValidator.ValidationGroup = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly CustomValidator _fooValidator = new CustomValidator
    {
        ID = "foo",
        Display = ValidatorDisplay.None,
        EnableClientScript = false,
        Enabled = true,
        ErrorMessage = "FooErrorMessage",
        SetFocusOnError = true
    };

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(this._fooValidator);

        this._fooValidator.ServerValidate += ValidateFoo;
    }

    protected static void ValidateFoo(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

now i'm calling the validation like

```
public partial class MyFooPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        // FooControl was added @ OnLoad
        // ValidationGroup of FooControl remains empty
        // this.GetValidators() returns the fooValidator of FooControl
        this.Validate();
    }
}
```

but the page remains valid, and the customValidator is not invalid.

i digged a bit deeper:

the `.Validate()`-method of the page, calls `.Validate()` on each validator, which internally calls `EvaluateIsValid()` of the `CustomValidator`:

```
protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
{
    string controlValidationValue = string.Empty;
    string controlToValidate = base.ControlToValidate;
    if (controlToValidate.Length > 0)
    {
        controlValidationValue = base.GetControlValidationValue(controlToValidate);
        if (((controlValidationValue == null) || (controlValidationValue.Trim().Length == 0)) && !this.ValidateEmptyText)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return this.OnServerValidate(controlValidationValue);
}
```

(c) by microsoft

which then calls `OnServerValidate` of the `CustomValidator`:

```
protected virtual bool OnServerValidate(string value)
{
    ServerValidateEventHandler handler = (ServerValidateEventHandler) base.Events[EventServerValidate];
    ServerValidateEventArgs args = new ServerValidateEventArgs(value, true);
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, args);
        return args.IsValid;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(c) by microsoft

according to the debugger, the `base.Events` contains a single event (my attached validation-method), but somehow it does not get fired...??!! i've also tried to set a breakpoint in the `ValidateFoo()`-method, which actually does not get hit.

can anyone tell me why, how i can get this working, what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution

```
public void Validate()
{
  this.IsValid = true;
  if (this.Visible && this.Enabled)
  {
    this.propertiesChecked = false;
    if (this.PropertiesValid)
    {
      this.IsValid = this.EvaluateIsValid();
      if ((!this.IsValid && (this.Page != null)) && this.SetFocusOnError)
      {
        this.Page.SetValidatorInvalidControlFocus(this.ControlToValidate);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(c) by microsoft

this is the `Validate`-method of `BaseValidator`.

if

- parent of the validator is not visible (with `Display` set to `None`)
- validator is not visible (with `Display` set to not-`None`)

the `IsValid`-flag won't get evaluated.